# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied')

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I want to query the database by id to display the data. I run into this error. "Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied')". Perhaps someone has encountered this error. Please tell me how to solve it.

Server

```
const express = require('express');

const lists = require('../models/lists');

const Description = require('../models/description');

router.get('/descriptions', (req, res) => {Description.find({ active: true }).then(descriptions => res.json(descriptions))});

router.get('/description-by-id', (req, res) => {let descriptionId = req.query.param1;
Description.findById(descriptionId).then( description => res.json(description));
});
 
router.get('/lists', (req, res) => {lists.find({ active: true }).then(lists => res.json(lists))`});module.exports = router;
 
 TS файл

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Component, Input, OnInit } из '@angular/core';

import { ScrollingModule } из '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

export interface List {
userId: String;
userId: String;
number: Number;
treatments: Array<any>;}
 
selector: 'app-invoices-form',

templateUrl: './invoices-form.page.html',

styleUrls: ['./invoices-form.page.scss'],})
export class InvoicesFormPage implements OnInit {
@Input() lists: List;
descriptionsArr: Array<any> = [];

constructor( private http: HttpClient, private scroll: ScrollingModule) {}
 
 ngOnInit() {
 if (this.lists.descriptions && this.lists.descriptions.length \> 0) { for (let item of this.lists.descriptions){ this.http.get\<any\>(`http://localhost:8100/description-by-id? 
 parameter1=${item.descriptionId})
 .subscribe((result: any) =\> { this.descriptionsArr.push({ 
        id: item.descriptionId, 
        name: result.name, 
        surname: result.surname
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```